# String Is Empty When Read

Tags: php, mysql, function

So basically I call a MYSQL query that grabs a secret key that was generated and saved to the database. Then it sets a string called "ServerCryptKey" to the output of the query which should be "yQnK9xDCxaLIGwzpsKEXeJR2Iz5ZoHnWyLHHikkQv5zbC8B5Sf36ZU9HteHSW5Ov".

```
$SQLGetUsers = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM settings");
while ($getInfo = $SQLGetUsers -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $NewServerHash = $getInfo['newhash'];
}
```

I can call the string fine and it will read the above ^, but whenever I have it call it from this function it reads nothing and shows it's an empty string...

```
function encrypt($data)
{
    $secret = $ServerCryptKey;
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}

function decrypt($data)
{
    $secret = $ServerCryptKey;
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}
```

If anyone can help me figure out why this doesn't grab the string, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Are you passing the string as $data to your decyrpt function and it is not working?

Comment: No, I am using the string as secret key for the encryption and decryption method. The $data is whatever I put in to decrypt or encrypt.

Comment: How are you setting the `$ServerCryptKey` in the code?

Comment: @srayhunter Through the MYSQL query that I first posted.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.  Do not report any passing errors on decryption.

Comment: I need to keep mc_crypt due to it is the only thing I can use to crypt on PHP and also crypt on VB to the same keys and stuff, anyone have a fix?